# Updating packages via nuget and problems with account controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth, nuget

I'm using visual studio 2012 update-2, and i'm working on an asp.net MVC internet application, recently i have updated MVC4 to MVC5 and EntityFramework 5.0 to EntityFramework 6.0.1 , OData and other packages too (i have updated every thing possible!) via nuget.

After getting some errors and working on upgrades, finally i was able to run the application!

But, i think there is a big problem with `OAuthWebSecurity` because whenever i try to use OAuth there is an error, specifically with Manage action in Account controller and Login page.

`OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount` brings the following error

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

---

Visiting Login page brings this error

> public class _Page_Views_account__ExternalLoginsListPartial_cshtml :
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage>
>
> The type or namespace name 'AuthenticationClientData' could not be
>   found

---

Some strange warning on rebuilding solution

> warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the
>   same dependent assembly.

Warnings in web.config and consider app.config remapping of assembly things :|

I'm confused!

What is wrong?!! Not using visual studio 2013 is the problem?!

Comment: Perhaps you still need to update the version numbers in the `web.config` file. Could you post the necessary data of that file?

Comment: i have updated the web.config, and the the application start to working and this OAuth problem is after that